# Problemas com <p:datatable> editável

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Boa noite. Estou com problemas para atualizar um datatable editável que criei aqui. Ele lê os valores, porém não os atribui ao objeto do ManagedBean para que eu possa persistir.

Segue Código do Bean

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
    }
}

public void prepararIndicadores() {
    indicadoresUsuario = new ArrayList<>();
    IndicadorAmbiental iamb ;

    for(IndicadorAmbiental ia : getIndicadores()) {
        iamb = new IndicadorAmbiental();

        iamb.setDescricao(ia.getDescricao());
        indicadoresUsuario.add(iamb);
    }
}

public void cadastrarIndicadores() {
    for(IndicadorAmbiental ia : indicadoresUsuario) {
        ia.setAno(anoFinal);
        ia.setCenario(cenario);

        //indicadorAmbientalDAO.salvar(ia);
    }
}
```

Código da View

```
    <p:dataTable var="i" value="#{cenarioBean.indicadoresUsuario}"
        paginator="true" rows="15" class="dataTable" id="dataTable" editMode="cell"
        emptyMessage="Nenhum Indicador Cadastrado" widgetVar="indicadores"
        paginatorPosition="bottom" editable="true" >

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{cenarioBean.onCellEdit}" /> 

        <p:column headerText="Nome" styleClass="column">
            <h:outputText value="#{i.descricao}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Valor" styleClass="column" width="300">
            <p:cellEditor> 
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{i.valor}"/></f:facet> 
                <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{i.valor}" stepFactor="0.5" size="47" styleClass="componentePF text" /></f:facet>  
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

A edição dos campos abre, mas não me permite fazer alterações. Se alguém puder dar uma luz, agradeço!!!

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o código da dataTable está dentro de um  e se os atributos da classe usada tem getters e setters

Comment: Tinha tudo isso! Criei um método auxiliar pra auxiliar na imputação dos valores.